# Regex for redirect urls

Tags: regex

Is there a single regex that can match these url redirect cases? I've been attempting for hours now and the closest I've gotten is `.*[^c|p]\/.*` but it does not match for `/p` or `/c`
https://regex101.com/r/ezb0jX/1

```
SHOULD NOT MATCH:
c/this-should-not-match
p/this-should-not-match

SHOULD MATCH:
p/
c/
z/this-should-match
product/this-should-match
collection/this-should-match
```

Comment: Can you reverse the result of `^[cp]\/.+` regex? It matches what you need to fail and looks simple. Otherwise, the answer below should work for you, unless you are using RE2 or other regex library that does not support lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

If it supports negative lookahead, this should work:

```
^(?![cp]\/.).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/kOphEG/1